# unable to put multithreading logic in this python code

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, networking, scp

Is there a way to use multithreading here, so that if 4 nodes are created, the file will be sent parallely to 4 nodes.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

import os

x = raw_input("Enter no. of nodes you want to create: ")
print "\nEnter ip as follows -- 1 192.168.0.1 \n"
d = dict(raw_input().split() for _ in range(int(x)))

for i in d:
    os.system("sshpass -p 'abc@abc' scp /root/Desktop/abc.py root@" + d[i] 
+":/root/Desktop/md/")
    print "configured successfully " + i
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered, so they won't be iterated in a certain order, like numeric order. Perhaps you want a list instead.

Comment: What Chai T. Rex said, plus you might want to be friends with the [OrderedDict class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)